# Dynamically creating a view

Tags: database, database-design, dynamic, view

I have a requirement to create a view whose query is dynamic.

Create or Replace View v_sample
AS
v_query;

The problem is I do not want to provide grants to the user who will be submitting the dynamic query to compile the view. Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't create the view.  Use dynamic SQL.